# Windows exe program work in safe mode but error in normal (access, permissions error)

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, path, accessibility

I have installed the program "VMS" needed to configure the IP camera. When I run shortcut, program does not reacting at all. But after several attempts to run, an error appears.

> `Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.`

VMS.exe is the program for setup/viewing IP cameras (Video Surveillance). This program was provided to me by the seller. And **it works perfectly in safe mode** on my Windows 10 Pro x64. Also, I tried installing it on VirtualBox to Win 7 x32, works well too.

So I think the problem is only with my main system. I turned off Defender (added an exception for the file and directory), add all permission, try compatibility, but nothing helped.

Look like something block this program or some bad with a registry but I don't know what and how to check/fix.

I tried to completely remove the program from the computer and clean the registry and reinstall it.

I also manually searched the registry at the request of "VMS" and manually deleted everything that referred to VMS.exe

Also since the error refers to "access" I tried setting the properties/security/permissions for all users and on all points but that doesn't help either.

I've also tried running in compatibility mode and troubleshooter.

I would be grateful for any advice that can fix this error.

Comment: Your successive attempts are colliding with each other, that's all.  Try #N+1 cannot open some device if try #N is still using it.  Wait longer between attempts, or use Task Manager to make sure the previous attempt fully exited.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand what you mean. I just looked in the Task Manager, the new task does not appear at all. I also looked through Process Explorer program, sorted by startup time, and tried to run. Nothing appears in the processes.

Comment: Check Windows Event Log for application errors.  Run Process Monitor (made by same division of Microsoft as Process Explorer) and check what errors there are.

Comment: @BenVoigt I used Process Monitor and filtered by Process Name "VMS.exe" and then run the program, and this show me 10 rows. 9 of these have the result column "Success", except one that has "NAME NOT FOUND" Operation: "RegQueryValue" Event class: Registry. Does that tell you anything? How can I share with you more information, like screenshots, etc? Event Viewer does not show anything while the program is running.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was in a hurry. When I ran it again after a while, I got a much larger list of 772 events with statuses: "SUCCESS", "NAME NOT FOUND", "BUFFER TOO SMALL", "FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS", "REPARSE", "NO MORE ENTRIES".

Comment: When you use the "Edit" button under your question (above these comments), the question editor will have a tool for inserting images.  It may not have appeared before due to your low reputation, but I think you now have enough to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145817/discussion-between-russell-and-ben-voigt).

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it! It was some other program/process that run with Windows startup and conflicted with VMS. I turned off all, restart and step-by-step run programs from the list, and with one of them VMS wouldn't start ("FixCamera.exe" I think it was installed a long time ago with web camera), so I deleted it, and now all work perfect. That's how I fixed it. Hope it will help someone.